# Gitlab Runner download the maven dependency For each build , Don't get from cache!=

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci, nexus, gitlab-ci-runner

I configurd the .gitlab-ci.yml, it is a java project and needs to maven repository, my local repository is nexus, I downloading the dependency from nexux successfully , but For each build it still downloads all the dependencies every time from nexus and it don't caching.

.gitlab-ci.yml configuration is :

```js
image: nexus.local.ir:8095/maven:3.6.3-jdk-8
######## run image #########
stages:
  - build

cache:
  key: maven-cache
  paths:
    - .m2/repository
######### cache ############
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn package -s config/settings.xml -Dmaven.test.skip=true
```

Comment: Does it download the JARs again? Or just the POMs?

Comment: it download the all dependency in pom again.